# How to define Oracle Package Procedure in H2 for Testing

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, testing, plsql, h2

I am testing an spring boot application that reads/writes data to an Oracle DB. This Oracle DB has Oracle packages and in those packages procedures. At some point, the spring boot application calls this procedure via a Entity Repository as follows

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A'); end;", nativeQuery = true)
public void setStudentGradeToA();
}
```

So, it uses a native query to make the call to to a procedure `Set_GradesToA` in the `STUDENT_PACKAGE` package of the `sch1` schema.

I am currently testing the functionality of the Spring Boot application and **NOT** the integration between it and the Oracle database. Therefore, I have decided to use an in-memory database (H2) (with the Oracle compatibility option) to replace the Oracle DB for now. **BUT how can I fake out these java package procedures?**

I have tried creating an alias in my schema.sql (or data.sql) as follows:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA if not exists sch1;
CREATE ALIAS sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE AS $$ void Set_Grades_To_A(String s) { new String(s); } $$;
```

I really don't care what is inside the `Set_Grades_To_A` procedure what I care about is how to define it.

When I create the alias as above, I'm still getting a Syntax Error.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "BEGIN SCH1[*].STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A'); END; "; SQL statement:
begin sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A'); end; [42000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:203)
```

I guess I have two questions:

1. How can I fake out a stored procedure inside an Oracle package in the schema sch1?
2. Why am I getting the Syntax Error above?

Comment: Thinking about my 2 questions I realized that these are 2 problems. Question 2, says that I have a syntax error in `begin sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A'); end;` I think I have to make a change to use `call sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A');` instead.

Comment: The closest answer i get to question 1 is from the accepted answer of [H2 database and functions in separate schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212347/h2-database-and-functions-in-separate-schemas). And the exact question I have is made by @Thiagarajan Ramanathan **the above solution worked perfectly If I have schema.functioname. But I have requirement where i have schema.packagename.functionname. How to handle that?**

Comment: This also asks the same question i am asking [H2 database create alias for function in package in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287700/h2-database-create-alias-for-function-in-package-in-schema), but with no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did.

**Question #2:** To answer this question I had to change the native query as follows

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

@Modifying
@Query(value = "call sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A')", nativeQuery = true)
public void setStudentGradeToA();
}
```

**Question #1:** Three things are involved to answer this. Now that I had changed the native query as above I got a different error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database "sch1" not found; SQL statement:
call sch1.STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A('A') [90013-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
```

It was looking for a database called `sch1`. It seems like the pattern used to call a stored procedure in H2 is `database.schema.procedure_name`. Since I don't care what that procedure actually does I was able to fake this out by creating a database called `sch1` a schema called `STUDENT_PACKAGE` and the procedure name `Set_Grades_To_A`

To create the in memory database, you have to set the following property `spring.datasource.url` in the `application.properties` file.

1. Create the `sch1` database as follows `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sch1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS first_schema`. Notice the database name is `sch1`
2. Create the `STUDENT_PACKAGE` schema by adding this `\\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT_PACKAGE` to the end of the `spring.datasource.url`. This adds a second schema called `STUDENT_PACKAGE`. The property should look like this `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sch1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS first_schema\\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT_PACKAGE`
3. Create a the `Set_Grades_To_A` stored procedure by adding this to your schema.sql `CREATE ALIAS STUDENT_PACKAGE.Set_Grades_To_A AS $$ void setGradesToA(String s) { new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(); } $$;`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding `IGNORE_CATALOGS=TRUE`

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;IGNORE_CATALOGS=TRUE
```

This will ignore the database name